# How to find in cakePHP using IN with comma separated strings.?

Tags: php, arrays, cakephp

I am doing a code where I have to find something where a bunch of strings are here. and put there something above code.

```
$status = "free","busy"
// In database there is work_status is saved either as free, busy, onduty.....

I have to find whether driver is free , busy. want to put an array into condition.
$this->Driver->find ( 'all', array( 'conditions' => array( 'Driver.work_status' => array( $driver_status ) ));
```

but empty array returned... can you help me out?

Answer (score 3):

That's not even valid PHP code. Just pass an array to conditions, ant it will create IN query:

```
$status = array("free","busy");
$this->Driver->find ( 'all', 
  array( 
    'conditions' => array( 
      'Driver.work_status' => $status 
    )
  )
);
```